# debugging java on solaris

Tags: java, solaris

I  have a standalone java app which will connects to DASTABASE and then call SP and send a mail.  I am calling the app through Shell Script , the problem **i am facing is java code is struck, it is struck at a point where it has to call SP but i am getting connection though , there is no  exception thrown whatsoever , now how do i debug this** .I am running this on Solaris  i don't have permission to run dtrace too.

Environment details:

SOLARIS
  IBM JAVA
  ORACLE 11g

Answer (score 0):

Add logging output to your program: Log actions (before statements), log variables. 
Repeat  until you have found the problem.

As a general advice, add logging output during development. The time you spend in a debugger is sometimes better invested into adding logging output.